# Is it appropriate to traverse “readfds(fdsets)” directly when using select in winsock2？

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock2, tcpserver

I am studying select api in winsock2. fdRead is the fd_sets contains all the sockets that are able to read. I found in most arcticles readfds is not traversed directly. Instead, fdSocket is traversed and judged by FD_ISSET(FD_ISSET(fdSocket.fd_array[i], &fdRead)). I have tried both two methods and both works. So my question is: why not traversing readfds directly?

```
fd_set fdSocket;
FD_ZERO(&fdSocket);
FD_SET(sock_listen, &fdSocket);//add sock_listen to fdSocket
while (true)
{
    fd_set fdRead = fdSocket;
    if (select(NULL, &fdRead, NULL, NULL, NULL) <= 0) break;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)fdSocket.fd_count; ++i)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(fdSocket.fd_array[i], &fdRead))
        {
            if (fdSocket.fd_array[i] == sock_listen)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
fd_set fdSocket;
FD_ZERO(&fdSocket);
FD_SET(sock_listen, &fdSocket);//add sock_listen to fdSocket
while (true)
{
    fd_set fdRead = fdSocket;
    if (select(NULL, &fdRead, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) break;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)fdRead.fd_count; ++i)
    {
        if (fdRead.fd_array[i] == sock_listen)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a portability measure and an attempt to make code
look similar to POSIX spec. `fd_set` allowed to vary in implementation

Answer (score 0):

Directly accessing the contents of an `fd_set` struct is not portable across platforms (neither is directly copying `fd_set` structs, either).  The fact that `fd_set` uses a plain C-style array on Windows is just an *implementation detail*.

If you need to write portable socket code, using `FD_ISSET()`, `FD_COPY()` and other related macros is the portable solution.  Otherwise, don't use `select()` at all, use `(e)poll()` (`WSAPoll()` on Windows) instead, which allows you to manage your own array of sockets that the function simply updates with status info when called.